# How to Change Pagination into Infinite Scroll in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, pagination, infinite-scroll

I want to change this pagination page into infinite scroll. I'm using codeigniter. I  had already search about jquery and ajax but i don't really understand how to implement it in my code. So please help me to edit my pagination code into infinite scroll. . .  I had struggle for days. I will be so grateful if u can hep me. 
Thank you :)

HomeController.php

```
public function list_voucher($page=NULL, $orderBy=NULL)
        {
            if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
            {
                $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                $data['nama'] = $session_data['nama'];
                $data['id'] = $session_data['id_user'];
                $data['tipeUser'] = $session_data['tipe_user'];
            }
            else{
                $data['nama'] = "";
                $data['id'] = "0";
                $data['tipeUser']="";
            }
            $data['url_image'] = $this->imageUrl;
            $data['notif'] = '';
            $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/home_controller/list_voucher/';
            $data['jmlh_rows'] = $this->voucher->getAllDeals();
            $total_row = $data['jmlh_rows']->num_rows();
            $config["total_rows"] = $total_row;
            $config["per_page"] = 8;
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
            $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
            $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );
            $data['dataAllDeals'] = $this->voucher->getAllDealsPerPage($config["per_page"], $page, $orderBy);

            $data['no']=$this->uri->segment(3);
            $data['data_kategori'] = $this->jenismakanan->Getjenismakanan();
            $this->load->view('listalldeals', $data);
        }
```

View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>deals</title>
        <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Custom Theme files -->
        <!--theme-style-->
        <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />  
        <!--//theme-style-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Food shop Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Andriod Compatible web template, 
        Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyErricsson, Motorola web design" />
        <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
        <!--fonts-->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!--//fonts-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/move-top.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/easing.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1000);
                });
            });
        </script>
        <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/imgslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/slideout.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.wmuSlider.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.wmuGallery.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="menu">
            <h1 style="color:white">Menu</h1>
            <hr style="color:white;">
            <ul>

                <?php if($tipeUser=="user"){?>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/" style="color:white">Home</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4 style="color:white">Welcome <?php echo $nama;?></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/my_voucher/0" style="color:white">My Voucher</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/my_profile" style="color:white">Profile</a></h4></li> 
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/logout" style="color:white">Logout</a></h4></li>
                    <?php } else if($tipeUser=="restoran"){ ?>

                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/" style="color:white">Home</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4 style="color:white">Welcome <?php echo $nama;?></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/dashboard" style="color:white">Dashboard</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/voucher_management" style="color:white">Voucher Management</a></h4></li>
                    <!-- <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/redeem_voucher" style="color:white">Reedem Voucher</a></h4></li> -->
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/logout" style="color:white">Logout</a></h4></li>
                    <?php } else if($tipeUser==""){  ?>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/" style="color:white">Home</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/login" style="color:white">Login / Register</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/list_voucher" style="color:white">Voucher</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/list_restoran" style="color:white">Restaurants</a></h4></li>
                    <?php
                        if($data_kategori->num_rows()>0)
                        {
                            foreach ($data_kategori->result() as $rows)
                            { ?>

                                <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/Type/<?php echo $rows->id_jenis_makanan; ?>" style="color:white"><?php echo $rows->nama_jenis_makanan;?>
                                </a></h4></li>

                        <?php } } ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <main id="panel">
            <header>
                <!--header-->
                <div class="header-in">
                    <div class="container">


                        <!---->
                        <div class="header-bottom">

                            <div class="col-xs-1">
                                <button class="toggle-button"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-11">
                                <?php echo form_open('home_controller/search_bar');?>
                                <div class="search">
                                    <form>
                                        <input type="text" id= "input-keyword" name="input-keyword" placeholder="Search ..." value="<?php echo set_value('input-keyword')?>" >

                                        <input type="submit" value="">  
                                    </form><?php echo form_close(); ?> 
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <!---->

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!---->
                <div class="container">

                    <div class="specials">
                        <h2>List All Vouchers</h2>
                        <hr></hr>
                        <?php
                            if($dataAllDeals->num_rows()>0)
                            { $j=0;
                                $f=$no;
                                foreach ($dataAllDeals->result() as $rowAllDeals){ $j++;
                                    if($j%5==0 || $j==1){
                                    ?>
                                    <?php } ?>

                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/Details/<?php echo $rowAllDeals->id_restoran;?>" ><img src="<?php echo $url_image;?>restaurant/<?php echo $rowAllDeals->id_restoran;?>/deals/<?php echo $rowAllDeals->gambar_voucher;?>" class="img-responsive-search" alt="">
                                        </a>
                                        <center>
                                            <h3 style="font-size: 4vw;text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;"><b><?php echo $f+1;?>. <?php echo $rowAllDeals->nama_restoran?></b></h3>
                                            <h3 style="font-size: 3vw;text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">Valid until : <?php $date=date_create($rowAllDeals->masa_berlaku); echo date_format($date, "d-M-Y"); ?></h3>
                                        </center>
                                        <?php 
                                            if($rowAllDeals->sisa_voucher > 0) {
                                            ?>
                                            <h4 style="font-size: 2vw;text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;" align="center">AVAILABLE (<?php echo $rowAllDeals->sisa_voucher. ' Voucher'?> from <?php echo $rowAllDeals->jumlah_voucher. ' Voucher'?>)</h4>
                                            <?php }
                                            else{ ?>
                                            <h4 align="center" style="color:red; font-size: 3vw;text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">NOT AVAILABLE <br></h4>
                                            <?php }
                                        ?>

                                        <?php if($tipeUser=="user" || $tipeUser==""){ ?>
                                            <div class="actions">
                                                <?php 
                                                    if($rowAllDeals->sisa_voucher > 0) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <center><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/GetVoucher/<?php echo $rowAllDeals->id_voucher;?>" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i>Get Voucher</a></center><br>
                                                    <?php
                                                    }
                                                    else{ ?>
                                                    <center><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/GetVoucher/<?php echo $rowAllDeals->id_voucher;?>" disabled class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i>Get Voucher</a></center><br>
                                                    <?php }
                                                ?>
                                            </div>        <?php } ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php if($j%4==0){?><?php } ?>
                                <?php $f++; } 
                            } ?>

                    </div>

                </div></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p style="height:10px"></p>
                        <div id="pagination" align="center" class="pagination-wrapper">
                            <ul class="tsc_pagination pagination" align="center">

                                <!-- Show pagination links -->
                                <?php foreach ($links as $link) {
                                    echo "<li>". $link."</li>";
                                } ?></ul>
                        </div>
                    </div></div>
                    <!---->

        </header>
    </main>


<?php if($this->session->flashdata('message')) :     
echo "<script>alert('". $this->session->flashdata('message')."')</script>";
endif; ?>
</body>

<script>
    var slideout = new Slideout({
        'panel': document.getElementById('panel'),
        'menu': document.getElementById('menu'),
        'padding': 190,
        'tolerance': 70
    });

    // Toggle button
    document.querySelector('.toggle-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        slideout.toggle();
    });
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
    if( userAgent.match( /iPad/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPhone/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPod/i ) )
    {
        slideout.disableTouch();

    }
    slideout.disableTouch();
    // auto close
        slideout.on('open', function() {
            $( "#panel" ).click(function() {
                    return false; 
                });
            $( "#panel" ).click(function() {
                    slideout.close();
                });
        });

        slideout.on('close', function() {
            $( "#panel" ).unbind('click');
        });
</script>

<script>
    $('.gallery').wmuSlider(); 

</script>
</html>
```

Model

```
public function getAllDeals(){
    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from('voucher v');
    $this->db->join('restoran r', 'r.id_restoran = v.id_restoran');
    //$this->db->where('r.fitur_premium', 'y');
    $this ->db -> where('v.masa_berlaku >', date('Y-m-d'));
    $this ->db -> where('v.is_aktif', '1');
    //$this->db->limit(8,0);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query;
}

public function getAllDealsPerPage($num,$page, $orderBy){
    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from('voucher v');
    $this->db->join('restoran r', 'r.id_restoran = v.id_restoran');
    //$this->db->where('r.fitur_premium', 'y');
    $this ->db -> where('v.masa_berlaku >', date('Y-m-d'));
    $this ->db -> where('v.is_aktif', '1');
    if($orderBy == NULL){
        $this->db->order_by('id_voucher', 'asc');
    }
    else{
        if($orderBy == "scName"){
            $orderBy = 'nama_voucher';
            $order ='asc';
        }
        else if($orderBy == "scNew"){
            $orderBy = 'id_voucher';
            $order ='desc';
        }
        $this->db->order_by($orderBy, $order);
    }


    //$this->db->limit(8,0);

    $query = $this->db->get('', $num, $page);

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: please check this anwer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934667/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin-in-codeigniter